# Read multiple files from S3 using golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am a novice in golang.
I want to read multiple files from Amazon S3. I am using the [s3gof3r](https://github.com/rlmcpherson/s3gof3r) library.

The go routine is as follows:

```
for i := 1; i <= fileNo; i++ {
    go test(i, b)
}

func test(i int, b *Bucket) () {
    fmt.Println("Loading file no:" + strconv.Itoa(i))
    defer wg.Done()
    r, _, err := b.GetReader("testFile_" + strconv.Itoa(i) + ".htm", nil)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(r)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println("Completed file no:" + strconv.Itoa(i))
    r.Close()           
    }
```

This code works alright if I have about 200 files (i.e. 200 go routines reading from 200 files) but it crashes if I have to read more files (I have to read more than 10,000 files)

The error that i get is

```
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    panic(0x39fde0, 0xc8200100f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc8200d3f18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:176 +0x239
main.test(0x4c, 0xc8200bc8e0)
```

The error comes from using 'ReadFrom'. Is there a problem using ReadFrom in this way? Or is this a wrong way to accomplish the task of reading so many files?

Comment: check your errors first.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Comment: As JimB mentions, you perform a `r, _, err := ...` but do not check your error: it's perfectly possible that something goes wrong and the returned `r` is `nil`, which would explain your crash. You should handle that case first, making sure that `err` is `nil` before attempting to access `r`.

Comment: Sorry there was a type there. Its bytes.Buffer

Answer (score 0):

Probably you ran out of memory.

Is it a typo `buf := new(bytes.Reader)` in your example, did you mean `bytes.Buffer`? I guess so.

```
r, _, err := b.GetReader(...)
//...
n, err := buf.ReadFrom(r)
```

Check for errors there. Probably it will be bytes.ErrTooLarge in ReadFrom call.

> ErrTooLarge is passed to panic if memory cannot be allocated to store data in a buffer.

Comment: No, if you run out of memory, you will get an "out of memory" error. This is a nil pointer dereference.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what happens when you ran out of memory and internal  `bytes.Buffer`'s buffer is set to nil pointer. And since you did not check for the error, you are dereferencing nil pointer.

Comment: Good point, forgot that `bytes` package tries to return `ErrTooLarge` when it can. I would still check the error before making any assumptions though.